# Subtraction from obtained results using sql

Tags: google-bigquery

| date | follwer |
| --- | --- |
| 23-10-2022 | 1 |
| 22-10-2022 | 0 |
| 21-10-2022 | 1 |
| 20-10-2022 | 2 |

Total followers 250

Expected output:

| date | follwer |
| --- | --- |
| 23-10-2022 | 251 |
| 22-10-2022 | 250 |
| 21-10-2022 | 249 |
| 20-10-2022 | 247 |

I want to implement above result using sql can one one suggest me some solution

Comment: Your expected output may have an issue because on `22-10-2022` there were no followers, therefore this date should not be affecting the rolling sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output could be generated by this query:

```sql
SELECT date, 250 - SUM(follwer) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) + follwer AS follwer
FROM yourTabld
ORDER BY date DESC;
```